# Repeated pre-system installation bootup logs

Tags: boot

I installed my new Ubuntu 22.04 on December 29th 2023. When I check the boot history with `last reboot`, I get repeated logs of reboot from Nov 21 21:57 until the previous or the the next real reboot end. I have secure boot with Bios password enabled, Ubuntu Pro and ESET running. Furthermore, I fully shut down the hardware after usage. Can anyone explain this strange behavior?

```
...
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-18-generic Fri Feb 23 09:36 - 20:00  (10:23)
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-18-generic Tue Nov 21 21:57 - 21:04 (92+23:07)
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-18-generic Tue Feb 20 12:20 - 21:04 (2+08:44)
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-18-generic Tue Feb 20 12:14 - 12:18  (00:03)
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-18-generic Tue Feb 20 12:06 - 12:10  (00:03)
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-18-generic Tue Feb 20 09:29 - 12:05  (02:35)
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-18-generic Tue Nov 21 21:57 - 09:28 (90+11:31)
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-17-generic Tue Nov 21 21:57 - 09:28 (90+11:31)
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-17-generic Mon Feb 12 11:15 - 09:28 (7+22:13)
...
```

Comment: We usually look in `journalctl` nowadays. This might be a time sync problem. In between the actual time of the two entries, do you see any jumps forwards or backwards in clock time?